# Differential equation with a trigonometric coefficient for an Ultrasonic Horn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, power-series, change-of-variable

I'm trying to solve a differential equation for the modeling of an ultrasonic horn in wich his form is a catenary, and his differential equation for a wave involves a hyperbolic tangent. I have the solution for the differential equation, but I need to do the "steps by steps". I had transformed the trigonometric coefficient into a polynomial but I keep having problems with the series in the development of the solution (I'm using series for solving this) so if someone can give me a hand, because I don't know if I'm doing a good approach to the equation, I would be very grateful. Here is the equation:
$$\ v''+\frac{2k}{r}tanh(\frac{kx}{r})v'+\frac{w^2}{c^2}v=0$$

and here is transformed into a polynomial

$$ \frac{k^2}{r^2}(1+u)^2 v''+\frac{w^2}{c^2}v=0 $$

thanks in advance and I wait for your answers if someone knows. ($k, r, w$ and c are constants)

Comment: is here $$v=v(x)?$$

Comment: the solution Looks terrible, have you tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: the solution i get from books is this but i having a hard time to reach it:
\frac{1}{rcosh(frac{kx}{r}}(Acos(\sqrt (\frac{w^2}{c^2})-(\frac{k^2}{r^2}))))+Bsin(\sqrt (\frac{w^2}{c^2})-(\frac{k^2}{r^2})))))

Comment: @ A.Avila : what is $u$ in the second equation ?

Comment: should i post the solution for you?

Comment: the solution i get from books is this but i having a hard time to reach it:
$$ \frac{1}{rcosh(\frac{kx}{r}})(Acos(\sqrt (\frac{w^2}{c^2})-(\frac{k^2}{r^2}))))+Bsin(\sqrt (\frac{w^2}{c^2})-(\frac{k^2}{r^2}))))) $$

Comment: @J.Jacquelin : u is the varaiable name i choose for the change of variable

Comment: So in the second equation, $v = v(u)$ ?

Comment: $$ \frac{k^2}{r^2}(1+u)^2 \frac{d^2v}{du^2}  +\frac{w^2}{c^2}v=0 $$

Comment: What is the substitution you made to go from your first equation to your second one?  In other words, how are $x$ and $u$ related?

Comment: i put u equal to the tangent function and then i start to operate with the derivates. i have a picture with the proccess but i dont kow how to uploaid it

Answer (score 1):

Define $y(x)$ such that $v(x) = y(x)/\cosh(kx/r)$.  (**EDIT:** see below for why you might want to do this.)  Then we have
$$
v'(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh (kx/r)} y'(x) - \frac{k}{r} \frac{\sinh (kx/r)}{\cosh^2 (kx/r)} y(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh (kx/r)}  \left[ y'(x) - \frac{k}{r} \tanh \left( \frac{kx}{r} \right) y(x)\right],
$$
and (after a fair amount of algebra),
$$
v''(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh (kx/r)}  \left[ y''(x) - \frac{2k}{r} \tanh \left( \frac{kx}{r} \right) y'(x) + \frac{k^2}{r^2} \left( 1 - 2 \,\mathrm{sech}^2 (kx/r) \right) y(x)\right].
$$
Thus,
$$
v''(x) + \frac{2k}{r} \tanh \left(\frac{2k}{r} \right) v'(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh(kx/r)} \left[ y''(x) + \frac{k^2}{r^2} \left( 1 - 2 \,\mathrm{sech}^2 (kx/r) - 2 \tanh^2 (kx/r) \right) y(x)\right] \\
= \frac{1}{\cosh(kx/r)} \left[ y''(x) - \frac{k^2}{r^2}  y(x)\right],
$$ 
since $\tanh^2(x) + \mathrm{sech}^2(x) = 1$.  Plugging this into the original ODE we have
$$
v''+\frac{2k}{r}\tanh\left(\frac{kx}{r}\right)v'+\frac{w^2}{c^2}v = \frac{1}{\cosh(kx/r)} \left[ y''(x) + \left( \frac{w^2}{c^2} - \frac{k^2}{r^2} \right) y(x) \right] = 0.
$$
Since $\cosh(kx/r) \neq 0$, we can conclude that
$$
y''(x) + \left( \frac{w^2}{c^2} - \frac{k^2}{r^2} \right) y(x) = 0, 
$$
which is an ODE that you can probably solve in your sleep.

---

In general, if you have an ODE of the form
$$
y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0,
$$
you can always make a substitution of the form $y(x) = f(x) z(x)$ to rewrite it in terms of another function $z$.  After some algebra you get
$$
z'' + \left( p' + 2\frac{f'}{f} \right) z' + \left( \frac{f''}{f} + p \frac{f'}{f} + q \right) z = 0.
$$
A reasonable guess for $f(x)$ would be that function that causes the coefficient of $z'$ to vanish, i.e.,
$$
\frac{2f'}{f} = - p(x) \quad \rightarrow \quad f = \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{2} \int p(x) dx \right].
$$
Note that if we plug in $p(x) = \frac{2k}{r} \tanh (2kx/r)$, we get $f(x) = 1/\cosh(kx/r)$.  So that's nice.

In general, the remaining term proportional to $z$ will still be present in the transformed ODE, and will probably be some really ugly function of $x$.  We lucked out in this particular equation in that the quantity
$$
\frac{f''}{f} + \frac{f'}{f} p + q
$$
reduced down to a constant.  So this trick won't always work;  still, it's probably worth a shot if you have no idea how to solve a second-order ODE.

Note that this trick is similar to the use of [integrating factors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html) for first-order ODEs;  in that case, it's guaranteed to work because you don't have another term in the ODE to worry about.

Comment: I will confess that without knowing the solution ahead of time, I would not have guessed the ansatz I used in the first step.

Comment: well i have not tried that approach, i've been doing power series getting stucked in the recurrence equation so i will do that again and in parallel your approach. Thanks for tacking the time to answer!

Comment: This is great, I just wonder if there's any way to see this without any knowledge of the solution.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93:  See my edited answer.

Comment: i will work with this and all the other answers during the weekend, thanks everyone for answer me.
For opther cases of this kind of differential equation i've been using the method of frobenius but is really a good thing to have different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the second form:

Divide the whole equation by the constant coefficient of $v^{\prime\prime}$ to get $(1+u)^2v^{\prime\prime} + \left( \frac{rw}{kc} \right)^2v = (u^2+2u+1)v^{\prime\prime} +  \omega^2v = 0$. Let $v = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iu^i$, and differentiation term-by-term gives $v^{\prime\prime} = \sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_iu^{i-2}$. Substituting into the equation gives $\sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_iu^i + \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2i(i-1)a_iu^{i-1} + \sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_iu^{i-2} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty \omega^2a_iu^i = 0$. We want to shift the sums so that they all have same power of $u$ in them, which will let us factor it out of the sum. So, we have $\sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_iu^i + \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2i(i+1)a_{i+1}u^{i} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)(i+2)a_{i+2}u^{i} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty \omega^2a_iu^i = \sum_{i=2}^\infty i(i-1)a_iu^i + \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2i(i+1)a_{i+1}u^{i} + \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)(i+2)a_{i+2}u^{i} + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \omega^2a_iu^i + (6a_3 + 4a_2+\omega^2a_1)u + (\omega^2a_0+2a_2) = (6a_3 + 4a_2+\omega^2a_1)u + (\omega^2a_0+2a_2) + \sum_{i=2}^\infty u^i[\left(i(i-1) + \omega^2\right)a_i + 2i(i+1)a_{i+1} + (i+1)(i+2)a_{i+2} ] = 0$.

From here, you get that each coefficient of $u^i$ must be $0$, which gives you a recurrence relation which you can use to get the terms $a_i$ given some constants $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: well thanks for your answer!!! well now i know that i did the same approach so i have to fight with those series.

Answer (score 0):

Appropriate changes of function and variable leads to a second order linear ODE easy to solve :

[image]

If $\lambda>1$ change the exponential to sinusoidal functions.

Comment: i will work with this and all the other answers during the weekend, thanks everyone for answer me.
For opther cases of this kind of differential equation i've been using the method of frobenius but is really a good thing to have different approaches.